# Why cant time-crystals form in thermal equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, time-crystals

This would make time-crystals a practically useless source of work, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you consult the September, 2018, issue of Physics Today you will find an excellent article on time crystals by N Yao and C Nayak (p 41).  Paraphrasing their synopsis, time crystals result when the discrete time translation symmetry of isolated periodically driven systems is spontaneously broken.  They are a quantum manifestation of the complex behavior of classical chaotic systems which are inherently non-equilibrium in nature.